# Changing CAEAGLLayer colors of ios 6 Maps

Tags: opengl-es, maps, ios6, caeagllayer

With the new Apple Maps, the `MKMapTileView` does no more work and i try to figure out
how to manipulate the Layer (and its content) which is responsible for displaying the whole map. The `View/Layer` of interest is the `VKMapCanvas` layer, which is a `CAEAGLLayer`.

Is there any chance to subclass and overwrite/swizzle a method or implementation of this (`VKMapCanvas`)?